# Google Play services out of date. Requires 4242000 but found 4132534

Tags: android, sdk, google-plus, google-play-services

I did update my version of google play services at android SDK Manager and even downloaded google play services for froyo but i still have this on my logcat.

I am trying to connect my app to google+ to get user information..

I hope somebody can help me out. 
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: did u run on device, not in emulator?

Comment: i am doing my testing on device.

Comment: r u using google-play-services_lib as ur lib project?

Comment: yes i am using google-play-services_lib. i just followed instruction from "Getting Started with the Google+ Platform for Android": https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started. i took the library from <android-sdk-folder>/extras/google/google_play_services/libproject as instructed and found google-play-services_lib library there.

Comment: right! update ur existing any google play app on ur device, then lets see

Comment: Awesome! i think its now working. i just updated the google play services at play store. thanks for this. now i have a new error appearing but it's another story.. if you would put your respond as an answer i gladly accept it. cheers! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please follow these useful steps :

1. use this google-play-services_lib as a library project in your project.
2. Try to run on the device.
3. update your existing any google-play app on your device.